# how to view pdf using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, pdf, gridview, webforms

In my `WebForm` I have a `Button` Named `Uploadbtn`when I click that PDF's Location should saved in Database.I saved the uploaded pdf in a folder in the location `~/pdf/Accounts/BalanceSheet/` I used following code inside `ButtonClick` event `Block` for all these.

```
String fileName = BalanceSheet.FileName;
String fname = Filename.Text;
String location =  "~/pdf/Accounts/BalanceSheet/";
String filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(location,fileName);
int cId = Convert.ToInt32(CompanyName.Text);
String conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MJCdb"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString)) 
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE BalanceSheetTable SET Year='" + Year.Text + "',Q1='"+filePath+ "',FileName='" + Filename.Text + "'WHERE Clientid='" + cId + "'",con);
    con.Open();
    int updated=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    BalanceSheet.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath)); 
}
```

And this is how my table look like when the above code excecuted:

[image: and this is how my table look like when the above code excecuted]

These Codes work fine. My Problem is, in another `WebForm` I have a `GridView` Created with the Following code

```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

now what I wanted to do is when I `Click` on `LinkButton`, the pdf that saved as mentioned above should open in the same Tab of the Browser.

Comment: OT please use parameters in your SQL queries, don't just concatenate values that have been input by the user. Also, do you store year as a varchar instead of an int?

Comment: in the linkbutton-click, try redirecting to the generated PDF - does that help?

Comment: I don't know how to do it

Comment: I followed a youtube video to Do this but I don't understand How he retrieves pdf the video link is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7sswv6LyIw